# Enabling range-based for for type that has "end" member variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with [a vector type](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/include/igraph_vector_type.h#L29) that comes from a C library and looks similar to

```
struct Vec {
    int *stor_begin;
    int *stor_end;
    int *end;
};
```

I tried to enable range-based for loop for this type by creating free `begin()` and `end()` functions, but I am getting this error from clang:

> error: range type 'igraph_vector_int_t' has 'end' member but no 'begin' member

Is there a way (using C++11) to enable range-based for loops for such a type (which I cannot modify directly)?

---

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```cpp
// No problems with Foo

struct Foo {
    int *fooBeg;
    int *fooEnd;
};

int *begin(Foo &foo) { return foo.fooBeg; }
int *end(Foo &foo) { return foo.fooEnd; }

void testFoo(Foo &foo) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (const auto &x : foo)
        sum += x;
}

// Bar does not work because it has a member variable called 'end'

struct Bar {
    int *stor_begin;
    int *end;
};

int *begin(Bar &bar) { return bar.stor_begin; }
int *end(Bar &bar) { return bar.end; }

void testBar(Bar &bar) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (const auto &x : bar)
        sum += x;
}
```

Error from [gcc 7.2 / Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eSwkT31uC7sAjmGK):

```
prog.cc: In function 'void testBar(Bar&)':
prog.cc:26:26: error: range-based 'for' expression of type 'Bar' has an 'end' member but not a 'begin'
     for (const auto &x : bar) {
                          ^~~
prog.cc:26:26: error: expression cannot be used as a function
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine on gcc 8.x and clang trunk.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I did not realize that. I was using clang on macOS 10.14 (i.e. the latest that Apple provides right now) and the default in Wandbox (gcc 7.2).  Indeed, gcc 8 in Wandbox compiles it, even if set to C++11.

Comment: Looks like a bug.  The `end` member is tripping up the compiler.

Comment: Looks like a bug. As per [8.5.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.ranged#1.3.2), both `end` and `begin` members need to be found, otherwise the free functions `begin` and `end` should be used.

Comment: This makes me wonder, will range-based for loop work for a type that has a `begin` and `end` *data* member?

Comment: Fixed in g++ 7.4

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `begin` and `end` will be used, not `std::begin` and `std::end`.  And yes it will fail to compile is you have members `begin` and `end` that aren't functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`g++ 8.x` and `clang++ 8.x` (and newer) both compile your code: [live example on godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3RxG6Z).

This is very likely to be a compiler bug.

---

As [François Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7359094/fran%c3%a7ois-andrieux) mentioned in the comments, the Standard says:

> [[stmt.ranged]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.ranged#1.3.2)
>
> **1.2.2** if the *for-range-initializer* is an expression of class type `C`, the unqualified-ids `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of `C` as if by class member access lookup ([basic.lookup.classref]), and if both find at least one declaration, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `range.begin()` and `range.end()`, respectively;
>
> **1.3.3** otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(range)` and `end(range)`, respectively, where begin and end are looked up in the associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]). [ Note: Ordinary unqualified lookup ([basic.lookup.unqual]) is not performed. — end note ]

This seems to agree with my hypothesis of this being a bug. If only one of `.begin` and `.end` is found, then 1.3.3 should make your code well-formed.

Comment: If the code is fine isn't it absolutely a compiler bug?

Comment: "If the code is fine isn't it absolutely a compiler bug?" Maybe also the standard has a option for interpretation. Maybe newer compiler offers better choice of the given "options" :-) For the given problem the new compiler seems to be a good choice :-)